# Adding zeroed out rows if no data exists SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Datetime` column called `[Start Time]` that I use to pull a date from with the SQL code

```
convert(date, format([Start Time], 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 103) as [Date]
```

I then have other columns which are then grouped by `[Date]` eg

```
sum([profit]) as [DailyProfit]
```

All well and good. However because my date list is based on a field, I get missing rows when no data exists. ie if there are no sales on the 3rd of november my data goes

```
+------------+-------------+
|    Date    | DailyProfit |
+------------+-------------+
| 01/11/2019 |        5000 |
| 02/11/2019 |        4000 |
| 04/11/2019 |        4500 |
| 05/11/2019 |        3500 |
+------------+-------------+
```

What I want to happen is those rows being created but with 0s in all the fields.

```
+------------+-------------+
|    Date    | DailyProfit |
+------------+-------------+
| 01/11/2019 |        5000 |
| 02/11/2019 |        4000 |
| 03/11/2019 |           0 |
| 04/11/2019 |        4500 |
| 05/11/2019 |        3500 |
+------------+-------------+
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a CTE to generate a list of all dates, within a range (since you mentioned you don't have rights to create a table, hence you can't store a [dates tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-table-uses-part-i)).

```
Declare @FromDate   Date = '2019-01-01',
        @ToDate     Date = '2019-01-30'

;WITH TallyDates AS
    (
        SELECT @FromDate AS NextDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, NextDate) as NextDate
        FROM TallyDates
        WHERE NextDate <= @ToDate
        )
SELECT d.NextDate as [Date]
    , CASE 
          WHEN pt.[Date] IS NULL
              THEN 0
          ELSE pt.Profit
      END as DailyProfit
FROM TallyDates d
    LEFT JOIN ProfitTable pt
        ON d.NextDate = pt.[Date]
```

If you have the rights, you can also persist the results of this CTE in a temporary table and use it multiple times, since it is persisted per session.

The code would look like:

```
Declare @FromDate   Date = '2019-01-01',
        @ToDate     Date = '2019-01-30'

;WITH TallyDates AS
    (
        SELECT @FromDate AS NextDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, NextDate) as NextDate
        FROM TallyDates
        WHERE NextDate <= @ToDate
        )
SELECT NextDate
INTO #TallyDates_tmp
FROM TallyDates

SELECT d.NextDate as [Date]
    , CASE 
          WHEN pt.[Date] IS NULL
              THEN 0
          ELSE pt.Profit
      END as DailyProfit
FROM #TallyDates_tmp d
    LEFT JOIN ProfitTable pt
        ON d.NextDate = pt.[Date]
```

Comment: I don't have the access to create tables. I could possibly request one be set up but if there are solutions that don't require that I would prefer them.

Comment: @tomdemaine ok, I'll update my answer. Give me 2 minutes,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want it when you execute select statement.
You can try `select Date, COALESCE(sum([profit]),0) as [DailyProfit] default 0 from .... where ...)`